# How can I specify which build target includes a specific swift package dependency?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Using the swift package manager, I have a swift package included in my project and I would only like it to be available in the test target and ui test target. How can I choose the target which has access to the swift package?

Comment: Only those targets would import the package module?

Answer (score -2):

the easiest way would be to use cocoapods

your podfile would look like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!
  #These are the main app frameworks
  pod 'Alamofire'

  # Pods for MyApp

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    # here would be your testing frameworks
    pod 'MyTestFramework'
  end
  
  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
    # and here your UI tests framework
  end

end
```